# Check internet connection is available or not

Tags: c#, winforms, connection

I am trying to detect the internet connection, if the internet connection is available and it is connected, it will continue, otherwise it will throw message box says that the connection is not available.

What I am encounter is whether the internet connection is connected or not connected, the code will continue.

Here is the code:

**** The program will continue to `worker_ProgressChanged`, even though there is no internet connection available ****

```
public CheckUpdates()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bool checkConnection = CheckConnection.IsConnectedToInternet();

            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

            if (checkConnection == true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
                backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            }

            else
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                _sound.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("No connection available, please check your internet connection!", "No connection");

                if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Hide();

                    this.Close();
                }
            }

        }

        private void CheckUpdates_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            if (e.ProgressPercentage.Equals(100))
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                _sound.Play();

                DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("No updates were available!", "No updates");

                if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Hide();

                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;
        }

class CheckConnection
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll")]

        private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

        public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
        {
            int Desc;
            return InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0);
        }

    }
```

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's a lot of silly code that doesn't do anything you are showing us.  The backgroundworker is just looping.  The timer isn't doing anything.

Comment: Let me know who is calling the events CheckUpdates_Load or WelcomeScreen_Load

Comment: @Steve: I am sorry, the WelcomeScreen_Load is from another forms, I am just copy and paste everything on WelcomeScreen forms (because the welcome screen contains background worker too), and for the CheckUpdates_Load, that event will fired when I click the button that linked to the CheckUpdates form which I not show on above code (on how I call the CheckUpdates form)

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` in the event `WelcomeScreen_Load` or in the event `CheckUpdates_Load` without checking if the Internet is connected or not.  (Probably the `worker_ProgressChanged` is defined at design time withing the backgroundWorkder properties)

These events doesn't seems to be related  to a Form.Load event handler because your class doesn't derive from Form. However it seems clear that you need to put a check there otherwise whoever triggers these events will start your background worker.

```
    private void CheckUpdates_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(CheckConnection.IsConnectedToInternet())
             backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void WelcomeScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(CheckConnection.IsConnectedToInternet())
             backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, the WelcomeScreen_Load is from another forms, I am just copy and paste everything on WelcomeScreen forms (because the welcome screen contains background worker too), and for the CheckUpdates_Load, that event will fired when I click the button that linked to the CheckUpdates form which I not show on above code (on how I call the CheckUpdates form). Thank you for your answer though. I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Well, from the code above, there is no way to reach the worker_ProgressChanged event without starting the backgroundworker. I suggest to use the debugger, put a breakpoint in the CheckUpdates_Load and WelcomeScreen_Load and, if you hit the breakpoint, look at the stack window to find who is the caller

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but I am pretty sure that there is some nasty copy/paste mismatch (InitializeComponent, but no Form inheritance in the class constructor?)